# How to get __meteor_runtime_config__ variables from server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to write a Javascript component using meteor that is designed to be embedded into 3rd-party websites (i.e., a customer support chat kind of application). Ideally I'd like the user to be able to insert just a small chunk of javascript or a single `<script>` tag to use the application.

The problem is that for normal web pages, meteor dynamically generates and injects a `__meteor_runtime_config__` global variable that has a bunch of important meteor settings.

How can I either retrieve the value of this variable when I include the normal meteor `.js` bundle file, or (even better) build it into the bundle file when I deploy the meteor app?

Answer (score 3):

There is a 3rd party utility called the [Meteor Build Client](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-build-client) that allows you to extract the client part of any Meteor app, so you can then embed it in any webpage separately from the rest of your Meteor app (you then connect the extracted  client code with your deployed Meteor server via DDP). This tool might save you some time.

If you still want to know how to work with the `__meteor_runtime_config__` settings yourself, take a look at the [source of the Meteor Build Client utility](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-build-client/blob/df61e399135cc85988d3c283d87345f15036adbf/meteor.js#L142-L165) (as it takes care of this for you). I've posted the relevant portion below:

```
...
// ADD the SCRIPT files
var scripts = '__meteor_runtime_config__'+ "\n"+
'        <script type="text/javascript" src="'+ files['js'] +'"></script>'+ "\n";

// add the meteor runtime config
settings = {
    'meteorRelease': starJson.meteorRelease,
    'ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX': '',
    meteorEnv: { NODE_ENV: 'production' },
};
// on url = "default", we dont set the ROOT_URL, so Meteor chooses the app serving url for its DDP connection
if(program.url !== 'default')
    settings.ROOT_URL = program.url || '';

if(settingsJson.public)
    settings.PUBLIC_SETTINGS = settingsJson.public;

scripts = scripts.replace('__meteor_runtime_config__', '<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("'+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(settings))+'"));</script>');
...
```